# Como saber se o valor da MODEL é um arquivo?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Preciso saber se o valor que está em uma propriedade da MODEL da tela é um arquivo. Como eu poderia fazer isso em javascript?

[image: Model]

Comment: Por favor explique melhor pois, sua pergunta está muito vaga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você consegue checar isso utilizando o `instanceof`!

```js
let bn_escudi_time = new File(['arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3'], "file.txt");
let string = 'string';

console.log(bn_escudi_time instanceof File); // -> true
console.log(string instanceof File); // -> false
```